# choroplethr region? in R

Tags: r, geolocation, package, choroplethr

I'm trying to understand what the region field is from the `choroplethr' package in R.

```
library(choroplethr)
data("df_county_demographics")
```

This provides demographic data that I'm interested in. Ultimately I'd like to map this data to a collection of lat/long points that I have. Just trying to see how to accomplish this.

Any information or suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks

Image of the data:
[df_county_demographics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T2cX.png)

------------------------Solved----------------------------

```
data(county.fips, package="maps")
data(df_county_demographics, package="choroplethr")
popData <- merge.data.frame(county.fips, df_county_demographics, 
    by.x= "fips", by.y = "region")
```

Comment: Hi. Printing out and adding to the post the first lines of the data could help you getting more answers.

Comment: Thanks. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The region column is the [county FIPS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code).

If you want the plain-english name of the county, you can join / merge `df_county_demographics` with `?county.regions`.